# Rest calls fail when adding spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have a Spring boot project that works just fine.
I have a local ssh tunnel running to access some resources.
Spring knows about this tunnel because I added `-DsocksProxyHost` and `-DsocksProxyPort` as VM options.
If I add `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` as a dependency, all of a sudden the project fails to run and I am getting UnknownHostExceptions.
So it seems that upon adding spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch, Spring does not respect the VM options anymore.

Can anybody tell me what can be wrong?
I tried checking for transitive dependencies but I was unable to find those.

Thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: and did you configured the elasticsearch client properly? Is elasticsearch reachable from your pc? what is the stacktrace?

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the elastic stack itself because it fails even before the elastic bean is created.

Comment: so maybe you should edit your question and add more details...because if it fails then you should see some error there